# React- Component not updating after change in prop render through useEffect

Tags: reactjs, async-await, use-effect, use-state

```
const [Paid, setPaid] = useState(false);

const fetchTransaction=async()=>{
      const data=await response.get();
  
      if (data.docs[0].data().status === "COMPLETED") {
          setPaid(true)
      }
        
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      fetchTransaction();
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
      RouterCourse = () => {
        return (
          <CourseRoute path="/course" component={Course} pay={Paid}/>
        )
      }
  }, [Paid]);
  var RouterCourse = () => {
    return (
      <CourseRoute path="/course" component={Course} pay={Paid}/>
    )
  }

return(
    <div>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                {RouterCourse()}
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </div>
)
```

So inside the function Routercourse, which contains a customized PrivateRoute component is a variable added called Paid. This variable is defined using a hook. Paid is changed through the asynchronous function fetchTransaction (false to true), but the new value (true) is not used. How do I update the used value inside the returned {RouterCourse()}?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out you can define another state that initially is component with paid false then in useEffect change that component with setState  https://i.stack.imgur.com/306pw.png upload this image may help you this is similar to your problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. It's like, when I click on the button which leads to path /course, it resets the page and variable paid gets reset to false. I really don't know how to solve this